# how to nest imageView inside of another imageView programmatically on top of background layout in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to nest an `ImageView` on top of another `ImageView` that is on top of a background layout.  In other words, I want the nested `ImageView` to become like a child of the parent imageView and drawn on top.  This needs to happen when the top most `ImageView` is clicked on though, so it's not just something I can set up in an xml.  The problem is that I can't even get the top layer `ImageView` to be nested within the parent `ImageView` from the start of the program yet.  It just appears at the top left of the screen instead of in the middle of the parent `ImageView` (which is in the center of the screen approximately).  I would appreciate it someone could point out to me what the problem with my code is.

Here is the code for the main activity:

```
package com.cannibal_photographer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

    FrameLayout main = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.layout.activity_main);
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup boatview = (ViewGroup) li.inflate(R.layout.boatlayout,main,false);
    View personview = li.inflate(R.layout.personlayout,boatview,false);

    ((ViewGroup) main).addView(boatview);
    ((ViewGroup) boatview).addView(personview);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set both images inside a RelativeLayout. Get a reference to both ImageViews in your code, set the inner image visibility to View.GONE in your xml and set it to View.VISIBLE once the outer image is clicked.

Comment: The inner image starts out on a beach.  When clicked, it needs to become a part of the boat imageView, but you also need to be able to click on the inner imageView once it's on the boat imageView in order to return it to the beach.

Comment: Is that a riddle ? I'm not sure I understand the question ... :-)

Comment: There is a person imageView that starts off on a beach.  you click on the person imageView and it moves to the inside of the boat imageView.  The reason for this is that when the boat is tapped on, it moves too and the person needs to be able to move with it.  The person also needs to be able to return to the beach if they are tapped on again while on the boat.

Comment: In order to move the boat & person at teh same time, get a reference to the relative layout containing the 2 imageViews as I suggested, and move that, both images will move accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm starting to see how what you're saying could work and I really appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.  I'm just not sure if it will work with what I'm actually trying to end up doing so let me explain a little.  there will ultimately be 6 imageViews representing people and one boat imageView.  only 2 people will be able to board the boat at once and the user needs to be able to return particular people back to the beach if they change their mind about who to send across the river.  When the boat imageView is tapped, the people on the boat will be dumped on the beach

Comment: (continued from last comment) on the other side of the river.  Is what you're suggesting going to work for that?  Sorry, I'm just having a little trouble grasping fully how to implement that into what I'm eventually wanting to do.  Thanks your help, I really appreciate it.  I'm attaching a screenshot of what the game looks like so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Apparently I need one more reputation point to be able to post images.  Here's a link to the image.  

http://imageshack.com/a/img707/1763/7yii.png

Comment: Yeah, no need anyway, I'm starting to get the idea ;) Although you could achieve what you're talking about by replacing the drawable of the imageViews (hence showing the correct character image in the boat/on the beach), it's far from ideal and is not designed for that. Would you consider learning proper Android Games Development ? There are cool resources around for that, like http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1753131 for example ... It's better to take the time to learn the right tools IMHO, even if it takes more time. Gave development is not exactly trivial :)

Comment: Ok, it sounds like I've found the answer I was looking for.  I can't do what I'm wanting to do the way I thought I could do it.  I'm really just looking for the best way to achieve making this game because I want it to look professional to potential employers and the resource you sent seems to cover a lot of what I've been wanting to know all in one place.  Hopefully by absorbing as much of that as I can, a solution will arise.  Anyway, thank you for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome ! Motivation is the key, if you have it (and of course, time), keep at it and I'm sure you'll get there ! Best of luck ;)